# Yoast purge plugin caused crawl errors, getting more even after removing it

Tags: redirects, wordpress, images, crawl-errors

I'm using the Yoast SEO plugin on my WordPress site, and when you upload media to WordPress media library, it makes a copy of the image or file and creates a file path (this is normal).

However, all of my images are getting indexed and are returning 410 'Gone' errors, though they still appear.

I removed the Search Index Purge plugin (also made by the Yoast team) and now those image file paths return a 301 redirect to the image file itself (not the URL created for each image).

However, in Google Search Console, I'm still getting crawl errors for each of these images (over 3,000 of them).

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Is there a work around so I can keep these images from being indexed without removing them from the media library?

Comment: What is the crawl error that Google is reporting?  If it still says they are 410, then you may just need to wait a few months until everything gets recrawled.

Comment: Fixed! I removed the Search Index Purge plugin and the 410 disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my site where I have a lot of images (as a photographer.) When I had the Search Index Purge plugin installed, I got many errors in GSC and "broken" images when I found them in Google Image search. I wrote to Yoast support but they did not answer.

To solve this issue, I had to delete this plugin and install RankMath.